# NativeScript TextField canPerformActionWithSender

Tags: nativescript, textfield, nativescript-vue

I have a custom keyboard (made from buttons) in my app and I'm using it to populate a numeric value into a `TextField`. When a button is pressed, I set the text of the `TextField` while sanitizing the data — making sure there's only 1 decimal, no letters are entered, etc.

However, I'm now trying to detect when a user attempts to paste into the field so I can either prevent it entirely or sanitize the pasted text before allowing it to be pasted.

The approach I've taken so far is to try to implement the [canPerformActionWithSender](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621105-canperformaction?language=objc) method on a NativeScript `TextField`.

I've tried the following (I'm using NativeScript Vue):

```html
<TextField 
    ref="amount" 
    hint="$0.00" 
    @loaded="onTextFieldLoaded" 
    @unloaded="onTextFieldUnloaded" />
```

And...

```
onTextFieldLoaded(event) {
    let textField = event.object
    textField.focus()

    nativeView.canPerformActionWithSender = (action, sender) => {
        // `action` may be 'paste' so I can handle that action here
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there an easy way to accomplish this without creating a custom component?

Comment: I think you will have to extend the `UITextField` to override this method and return instance of same in `createNativeView` method of `TextField` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following:

```
UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender = function (action, sender) {
    return false;
}
```

This will disable the copy/paste/etc. menu completely. You can be more specific and check the action to only disable certain functionality if you like.

```
UITextField.prototype.canPerformActionWithSender = function (action, sender) {
    if (action == 'paste:') { 
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```